# How can I let our DirectShow-based video be captured by a screen recorder?

Tags: video, directx, directshow, video-capture

One function of our software plays a video with DirectShow. One user and our internal QA have found that screen capture utilities (including Captivate, Camstudio, and AVS4U's capture utility) cannot record the video playing onscreen along with the other onscreen data.  The area with the video is captured either as a black rectangle, or only ever shows the first frame.

**How do I render DirectShow video to screen so that video capture utilities can capture the playing video** along with all other onscreen (normal GDI-drawn) data on surrounding windows?  Lots of details about the problem below.

**Notes:**

- I can't reproduce the issue on my development computer, which is making it a bit tricky to solve.  I use Windows 7 running in VMWare Fusion 3 on OSX, and capturing still images with the Snipping Tool and via the Print Screen key, and capturing screen videos with CamStudio and AVS4U, all work fine.  However, both one customer and two QA staff can reproduce the issue running Windows 7 natively.  All drivers etc on my VM and their PCs are up to date.  I don't have exact hardware and driver information for the affected customer, but I can get it for the in-house QA staff's computers.
- My working theory is that the video is rendering using an overlay or other video-hardware-based mechanism bypassing GDI entirely, and so the capture utilities don't ever see the video data, and that for some reason this is not the mechanism used when DirectShow runs on my machine.  I am not sure how to check this.  The graph manager does not send a `EC_VMR_RENDERDEVICE_SET` event that would let me see which mechanism of (overlay, video memory or system memory) is being used.
- One idea for solving it was to listen for an event notification that was sent every frame, then use [`IBasicVideo::GetCurrentImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the current frame image (and [position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and render it to screen with GDI.  However, there doesn't seem to be [any event sent every frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Specifically, the only events I see are:

  - Opening the video window and showing a paused still video: `EC_VMR_RENDERDEVICE_SET`
  - Stepping the video: `EC_PAUSED` and `EC_STEP_COMPLETE`
  - Playing the video: nothing at all - it plays without firing any events whatsoever.
- Another idea is to insert a new graph filter item, which capture the frame every frame and lets it be drawn to screen with GDI.  I don't know if this is a good approach, or where to start to write such an item.  If this is the best solution, a great answer would have a short code example showing how to write one to get the frame data.  (I don't know if this is the best solution though, although I suppose I just need to get 'a' solution, not the best.  Naturally I would prefer the 'right way', whatever the right way is, if possible.)
- Another idea is to write an [alternative video renderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), though MSDN recommends on that page to use either a Video Mixing Renderer or Enhanced Video Renderer instead.  VMRs appear to be DirectX-based, so if my theory about the problem is correct doing this probably won't help, unless I use something like D3DX to get the surface data as an image (?), and EVR is Vista and above only.  Writing an AVR seems fairly complex and I am not 100% certain if it would help me achieve what I need to, which I'd like to be before writing one.
- Video is currently rendered through [IVideoWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not `IVMRWindowlessControl` or `IVMRWindowlessControl9`.  I can of course change this if there's something about one of these interfaces / implementation that would help it work.
- The code is written in native C++, not .Net, though a solution in any language would be great.  The minimum supported client is Windows XP.

I will appreciate any advice on the problem, and a great answer would provide a small code sample (it would be good to have something known working to work from.)

*I should note too that screen capture to grab the video is entirely legitimate.  Our software is scientific visualisation and analysis software, and the videos our users are playing are their own recordings.  Our software can display this video along with non-video data recorded from other sources.  Screen capture tools are used for recording demos, presentations, online videos about research, etc - i.e. legitimate reasons to capture video playing in combination with surrounding stuff onscreen.*

Thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just avoid using overlays when rendering video. There are a few ways to:

- use custom renderer, esp. GDI based, which guarantees ability to capture - [`SampVid Filter` sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on older Windows SDK and/or DirectShow SDK
- set flags/settings to prevent use of overlays - [`IVMRFilterConfig::SetRenderingPrefs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`IDirectDrawVideo::SetSwitches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd406828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- create fake graphs or filters in order to lock all available overlays before starting actual playback, so that your video of interest is displayed through non-overlay code path inside the standard video renderer component - fake instances until [`IDirectDrawVideo::GetSurfaceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd406824%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns non-overlay type it had to fall back to

Comment: Thanks Roman. Do you have any details about any of those, or pointers where to look for, for example, creating a fake graph to lock overlays or for creating a custom GDI renderer?